# I can't figure out React Hot Loader. My bundle.js is valid and my server connects, but I am seeing a cannot GET message in the browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I can get webpack to run and the server connects, but all I see in the browser is a cannot GET message. Could someone see if they can spot where I am messing up the configuration. All my components are in a file called public, so in relation to the webpack.config.js file that would be'./public'

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
    './public/index.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  output: {
   path: __dirname,
   filename: './public/bundle.js',
   publicPath: './public/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      App: 'public/components/App.jsx',
      Home: 'public/components/Home.jsx',
      Footer: 'public/components/Footer.jsx',
      Inventory: 'public/components/Inventory.jsx',
      Login: 'public/components/nav/Login.jsx',
      Navbar: 'public/components/nav/Navbar.jsx',
      ProductSearch: 'public/components/Product-Search.jsx',
      SingleProduct: 'public/components/Single-Product.jsx',
      Product: 'public/components/Product.jsx',
      Signup: 'public/components/Signup.jsx',
      LandingNavbar: 'public/components/nav/LandingNavbar.jsx',
      ProductSearch: 'public/components/ProductSearch.jsx',
      Examples: 'public/components/Examples.jsx',
      Pricing: 'public/components/Pricing.jsx',
      Profile: 'public/components/Profile.jsx',
      Checkout: 'public/components/Checkout.jsx',
      Receipt: 'public/components/Receipt.jsx',
      RequireAuth: 'public/components/auth/require_auth.jsx',
      Signout: 'public/components/Signout.jsx',
      Tour: 'public/components/tour/Tour.jsx',
      BusinessTypes: 'public/components/tour/BusinessTypes.jsx',
      Customers: 'public/components/tour/Customers.jsx',
      Features: 'public/components/tour/Features.jsx',
      GettingStarted: 'public/components/tour/GettingStarted.jsx',
      MultiStore: 'public/components/tour/MultiStore.jsx',
      Support: 'public/components/tour/Support.jsx',
      Actions: 'public/actions/index.js'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
   loaders: [
      {
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'], 
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();
const router = require('./router');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const serverConfig = require('./config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

// DB Setup for mlab

mongoose.connect(serverConfig.database, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the database");
    }
});

// Connects to local database

// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:auth/auth');

// App Setup

app.use(morgan('combined')); //logs incoming requests

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' })); //parses incoming requests into JSON, '*/*' accepts any type of request

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //serves public folder containing front-end

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); //serves index.html when home route is hit

});

router(app);

//Server Setup


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// Webpack dev server below

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(port, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should point your publicPath to "http://0.0.0.0:3000/" since you are running this through a server.